# How do I overload my case class constructor to allow two different types?

Tags: scala, constructor-overloading

Right now I have a `RealVector` class and `ComplexVector` class. The logic for them is almost identical, so I'd like to combine them into a single `Vector` class. `RealVector` takes a `List[Double]` whereas `ComplexVector` takes a `List[ComplexNumber]` where `ComplexNumber` is a case class I created.

How do I make it so my `case class Vector` accepts either of the two `List` types? Note that while the code for most methods are identical, some of them may return a `Double` or `ComplexNumber` depending on the `List` type. Is it even correct to be using a case class in this instance, or should I be using a normal class?

edit: my current code

```
trait VectorElement[A]
implicit object RealVectorElement extends VectorElement[Double]
implicit object ComplexVectorElement extends VectorElement[ComplexNumber]

case class MyVector[A: VectorElement](components: List[A]) {
    def +(that:MyVector[A]):MyVector[A] = {
        if (this.dimension != that.dimension) throw new Exception("Cannot add MyVectors of different dimensions.");
        new MyVector((this.components zip that.components).map(c => c._1 + c._2));
    }

    def -(that:MyVector[A]):MyVector[A] = {
        if (this.dimension != that.dimension) throw new Exception("Cannot subtract MyVectors of different dimensions.");
        new MyVector((this.components zip that.components).map(c => c._1 - c._2)); // ERROR HERE: error: value - is not a member of type parameter A
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Too broad to get constructive answer, as rather than overloading that could be various better solution, as `trait`, genericity, typeclass, ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: An auxiliary constructor is required to call the primary constructor, which could make it hard for methods to determine which constructor was used.

Answer (score 2):

The most familar way would be to create a common super type of your two Vector classes

```
abstract class Vector[A](elements: List[A]){
  //common code
}
case class RealVector(elements: List[Double]) extends Vector[Double](elements)
case class ComplexVector(elements: List[ComplexNumber]) extends Vector[ComplexNumber](elements)
```

---

If you just want a single type can use Generics with case classes so `case class Vector[A](values: List[A])` works.

Now this will allow any kind of List, so lets narrow it down.  We could use a common supertype from a trait if we were dealing with custom types, but `Double` is built in and we can't modify it.

What we can do is use a typeclass, this is a flexible form of polymorhism possible in scala.  We can Define our typeclass with a trait.

```
trait VectorElement[A]
```

If we just want to use it to mark the types we want we are done, but we could also put common functionality that we need into here as well.

If we modify our case class definition to

```
case class Vector[A: VectorElement](values: List[A])
```

We restrict our generic type to only those types with a VectorElement instance available.  The above code is syntactic sugar for `case class Vector[A](values: List[A])(implicit ev: VectorElement[A])`

we can now create instances for the types we need

```
implicit object RealVectorElement extends VectorElement[Double]
implicit object ComplexVectorElement extends VectorElement[ComplexNumber]
```

now as long as those two implicit objects are in scope we can use those types with our `Vector` class but no others.

---

Some unrelated suggestions:

`Vector` is already a class from the standard library which is always automatically imported, this has the potential to cause problems

`List` is probably not the best collection type for this as it needs to traverse the collection to access it's elements.  Likely you want to choose something more generic, and you probably want good indexed access.  If you use `IndexedSeq` instead of `List` as the collection type, you can ensure that you are working with a collection with good index-based random access like `Array` or `Vector` (the one from the standard library).

Comment: After doing this, I am getting the error `error: value - is not a member of type parameter A`, but I have `-` overridden/defined for `ComplexNumber` and an implicit conversion for the `Double`. Any idea why? And thanks for the heads up on IndexedSeq. I wanted something immutable which is why I didn't use Array.

Comment: @Mike I'd need to see your code.  Where are you trying to call value?  I suspect it's because your trying to call it on the `A` type.  Remember, you won't be able to call the ComplexNumber methods on the `A` type, because the two aren't related.  You should define any methods you need inside the typeclass.

Comment: I added my code as an edit. I think you're right about my issue. I don't think I want a solution where I cannot use my `ComplexNumber` methods though, since I don't want to have to define my methods in my typeclass AND in `ComplexNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using some of the more advanced Scala type system features:

```
object Types {
  trait inv[-A] {}
  type Or[A, B] = {
    type check[X] = (inv[A] with inv[B]) <:< inv[X]
  }
}

case class Vector[U : (Double Or Int)#check](list: List[U]) {
  def first(): U = list.head
}
```

I've used `Double` and `Int` here but any type can be used. Usage is simple:

```
println(Vector(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)).first()) // prints a Double
println(Vector(List(1, 2, 3)).first()) // prints an Int
//Vector(List("String")).first() // won't compile
```